# Probability problem - handicap students and accomodation

Tags: probability

**Problem**

Suppose there is a 20% chance a given student is handicap. There are 18 spots for regular students and 5 spots for handicap students in a given class. Regular students must use regular spots and handicap students must use handicap spots. Then what is the probability that a class of 20 students is accommodated?

**Solution**

Consider 4 scenarios. The class has 2 handicaps and 18 regulars, 3 handicaps and 17 regulars, 4 handicaps and 16 regulars, and 5 handicaps and 15 regulars. Anything that is not any of these combinations is not accommodated fully.

Then the probability is

$$\sum_{i=2}^5\left(\frac15\right)^i\left(\frac45\right)^{20-i}$$

which was verified by the professor.

**Question**

Another student brings up this question. Suppose I wanted to know the probability of having 3 heads and 7 tails in no particular order. Then I would have

$$_{10}\text C_3\left(\frac12\right)^{10}$$

because I would be counting the different possible combinations of coin flips which gives me 3 heads and 7 tails. Similarly, it's suggested the answer for the handicap problem is

$$\sum_{i=2}^5{}_{20}\text C_i\left(\frac15\right)^i\left(\frac45\right)^{20-i}$$

which does not coincide with the solution the professor provided. So why is this wrong? Or did the professor make a mistake? (He was in a hurry.)

Comment: Handicap is what you get when you play golf; the correct term is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your reasoning: as you found, the factor of $_{20}C_i$ needs to be there in order to obtain the desired probability. So you are correct, and if your professor omitted the factor $_{20}C_i$ then that was a mistake.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I've reworded it to answer the questions more directly.